# how to cancel highlighting the 80th column in vim?

Tags: vim, python, solarized

I use python-mode and solarized plugin in my vim, and I think either one of them sets highlight at 80th column, so that I get a visual on how long each line should be, but actually python-mode will throw errors if I ever exceeded 79 characters per line, so I don't really need this column hilight, could anybody help?

I've tried grep ColorColumn out of .vim/bundle, but nothing much showed up and I don't quite know which plugin exactly is causing this colorcolumn high lighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue, here, is that your configuration apparently does things you don't know about. *That* is what you must fix ASAP.

You can look for where `colorcolumn` was set with:

```
:verbose set colorcolumn?
```

and disable it temporarily with:

```
:set colorcolumn=
```

Comment: thanks, it's pymode, I'll override the settings myself and suggest a bit to pymode dev